# how to work with large csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have a very huge csv file and I have to use some select query, getting avg,... I can not do that normally by reading line by line, because of out of memory.

the following code work well on a short csv file but not for huge one.
I will appreciate if you can edit this code to use for large csv file.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Mu {
    public void Computemu()
    {
        String filename="testdata.csv";
        File file=new File(filename);
        try {
            Scanner inputstream=new Scanner(file);//Scanner read only string 
            // String data=inputstream.next();//Ignore the first line(header)
            double sum=0;
            double numberOfRating=0;

            while (inputstream.hasNext())
            {                       
               String data=inputstream.next();//get a whole line
                String[] values= data.split(";");//values separate by;
                double rating=Double.parseDouble(values[2].replaceAll("\"", ""));//change value to string
                if(rating>0)//do not consider implicit ratings
                {
                    sum+=rating;
                    numberOfRating++;
                }
            }
            inputstream.close();
            System.out.println("Mu is"+ (sum/numberOfRating));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why the above code would lead to an OutOfMemoryError: it only has one line in memory at a time.

Comment: Does Scanner load the entire file into memory first?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 2):

You didn't call [useDelimiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter) so the `next()` methods must load the whole file into a string if it hasn't a white space (the default delimiter).

This leads to an OutOfMemory Error.

If you want to use a Scanner, set the delimiter according to your needs.

But a CSV library (like [csvfile](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvfile/) would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of Apache Commons FileUtil for this use case.   This may not be what you are looking for in your question, but FileUtil usage is preferable to re-implementing it.

Specifically, please look at [lineIterator](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#lineIterator%28java.io.File%29) method.